# Work around for Safari scale (transform) bug

Tags: css, svg, safari, scale, render

Lately I recognized that Safari (as the only browser (besides IE I don’t know and care) seems to use some kind of cached rendered image version if a *scale* (enlarge) is put on an image, for example an svg.

Means that other browsers enlarge the svg as expected neat and sharp while Safari renders an image (even svg) blurred.

I guess he uses the once rendered *unscaled* version of an image and then scales this one instead of applying the scale to the original file.

Someone out there with a similar issue and what’s more important with a workaround for it? Or a method to force Safari to re-render the original image when scaled?

PS
iOS doing the same thing, by the way.

EDIT:
Sorry, but I cannot use the workaround of enlarging images by width and then display them downscaled and then scale them to 1. I need a real upscale here.

**EXAMPLE:**

http://www.seifertfragments.de/typeface/yves-saint-laurent/

Scroll down the page a little and find white image with numbers (“+ 1 3 7 8 9”).
Click on it to open the lightbox. If you click the magnifying glass letters get blurred. Not in Firefox, Chrome etc. Also on iPad.

Safari version 10.0.3

Comment: can you share your snippet? I doubt thats the case with Safari. Also please mention the Safari version used.

Comment: Hello Pankaj! Check the link I gave in the example if you like! Thanks!